# How to fill Java-managed Apache Arrow vector from JNI/C++ with zero copy

Tags: java, c++, apache-arrow

### Main question

I am working with Apache Arrow vectors, and I'd like some help on figuring out how to fill a vector from C++ code that was created in Java. I have figured out how to create them in Java, share them with native code, and read the contents. But creating a new vector in C++ and filling it using a builder is incredibly slow.

I would like to figure out how to do the following:

- Allocate an Arrow vector in Java and pass it to C++ code.

  - I assume this is the same as if I created a vector in Java that I want to read in C++; see below.
- Get a raw pointer in C++ and write directly to the memory allocated in Java.

  - I know how to get a raw pointer from a Buffer object, but not from something like an Int32Array.
- Finalize the vector, set the length, etc.

  - I have no idea at all how to do this.
- Be able to just read it in Java with minimal extra overhead.

---

### Appendix

For reference, here's how I have been exporting vectors from Java that I want to read in C++.

- In Java:

  - Have a RootAllocator manage a memory pool.
  - Allocate an Arrow vector using that allocator.
  - Call `vector.allocateNew` to reserve capacity.
  - Use `vector.set(index, data)` to fill the vector.
  - Call `vector.setValueCount` to finalize the vector.
  - Allocate an ArrowSchema and an ArrowArray.
  - Call `Data.exportVector` to populate them with data about the vector.
  - Pass the array and schema pointers through JNI.
- In C++:

  - Call `arrow::ImportArray` with the array and schema pointers
  - Use `ValueOrDie` and a static cast to get access to vector of the right type.
- Back in Java:

  - Read the vector data
  - call `close()` when finished to free memory.

I have found calling `vector_ptr->Value(index)` to be *incredibly slow.* Supposedly, there is a `raw_values` method that I should be able to use to get direct pointer to the data, but I can't figure out how to get access to that from an Int32Array.

Comment: Please show code instead of a description of the code.

Comment: Unless I am wildly off the mark, you can get a raw pointer by doing `array.data()->GetValues(0)`. But your bigger problem is that `importArray` transfers ownership of the data from Java to C++, so you somehow need to transfer it back?

Comment: Unfortunately, GetValues returns a const pointer, which indicates to me that if I were to strip away the const, the container might not be designed to handle the new values being added.

Comment: There is a very real difference between creating an array from scratch and filling an existing vector with data. Can you please edit your post with at least some pseudocode that explains what you are trying to do? Why is allocating from Java a requirement? How is the builder approach "incredibly slow"?

Comment: The other thing is: why allocate it in Java? Why not make a JNI call, have the C++ _allocate and fill_ the vector, then export the array from C++ to Java?

Comment: And for why Value() is slow, and why you can't get more direct access: what have you tried, and what isn't working?

Comment: I'm comparing Apache Arrow to nio off-heap buffers. Value() is slow because it goes through multiple layers of abstraction for each access. I can get a raw pointer, and that helps. For writing, I can't seem to find a way around using an ArrayBuilder, and AppendValues requires a copy. Then the import/export operations to change ownership are very expensive.

Comment: I've done a variety of benchmark comparisons between using nio buffers and Arrow, and using nio buffers is orders of magnitude faster for allocation and access by both Java and native code.